# cmd.exe Command Line Parsing of Environment Variables

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I can't figure how to have cmd.exe not interpret something like `%PATH%` as an environment variable.
Given this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    printf("cmd line: %s\n", GetCommandLine());
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have these different outputs according to the position of the arguments:

```
>args "k\" o" "^%PATH^%"
cmd line: args  "k\" o" "%PATH%"
0: args
1: k" o
2: %PATH%

>args "^%PATH^%" "k\" o"
cmd line: args  "^%PATH^%" "k\" o"
0: args
1: ^%PATH^%
2: k" o
```

I guess it's because cmd.exe doesn't recognize the escaped `\"` and sees the escaped double quote as closing the first, leaving in the first case `%PATH%` unquoted. I say this, because if I don't quote the argument, it always works:

```
>args ^%PATH^% "k\" o"
cmd line: args  %PATH% "k\" o"
0: args
1: %PATH%
2: k" o
```

but then I can have no spaces...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently possible by also escaping the quotes:

```
>args ^"oo \\\^" \^" ^%PATH^%^"
cmd line: args  "oo \\\" \" %PATH%"
0: args
1: oo \" " %PATH%
```

So from what I gather these are the escaping rules:

#### For the C runtime/`CommandLineToArgvW` tokenization

1. Replace `\"` → `\\"`
2. Replace `"` → `\"`
3. Surround the result with double quotes.

#### For cmd.exe parsing

- Escape the characters <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd>, <kbd>&</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>%</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> by adding the escape character <kbd>^</kbd>.
- Escaping spaces is unnecessary is the C runtime escape rules were applied and cmd.exe is only to pass the arguments to an another program.

These transformations should be applied in order, first the C runtime rules and then the cmd.exe rules.

If writing something to be interpreted directly by cmd.exe, only the cmd.exe rules should be applied; if starting a program in a way that doesn't involve cmd.exe, only the C runtime rules should be applied.

Here's an example of an argument interpreted directly by cmd.exe, which writes to a file named `oo %PATH%`:

```
echo test > oo^ ^%PATH^%
```

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer. Thanks for posting your findings. I was monitoring this question since yesterday when I realized I didn't know the answer! ;-)

Comment: Is there any reference to the "cmd.exe parsing"?